# preview image before upload using jQuery

Tags: image, preview

I have 4 input[type="file"] that allow user upload 4 images.Now how can i preview all the choosen image in each input[type="file"] before upload ?

I have tried below code.But it will show same image in each input [type="file"]

```
 function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $("#vehicle-pickup-img-tag1,#vehicle-pickup-img-tag2,#vehicle-pickup-img-tag3,#vehicle-pickup-img-tag4").attr('src', e.target.result);

    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
   }
$("#vehicle-pickup-img1,#vehicle-pickup-img2,#vehicle-pickup-img3,#vehicle-pickup-img4").change(function(){
readURL(this);
  });
```

Comment: Did you got a solution? I got stuck in same issue.